# Lifting a semicommutative von Neumann algebra into an algebra of operator-valued functions

Tags: measure-theory, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Given a complete probability space $\Omega$ and a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal M$, it is well-known that the tensor product von Neumann algebra $\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M$, as the dual of $\mathrm L^1(\Omega,\mathcal M_*)$, can be identified with the quotient of certain space of functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathcal M$ in the following manner :

if we denote by $\mathscr L_{*}^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal M)$ the complex vector space of all essentially bounded functions $f:\Omega\to\mathcal M$ such that for all $x\in\mathcal M_*$, the function $\omega\mapsto\langle f(\omega),x\rangle$ from $\Omega$ to $\mathbf C$ is measurable, then $\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M$ can be identified with

$$\mathscr L_{*}^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal M)\Bigg/\biggl\{f\in\mathscr L_ {*}^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal M)~\bigg|~\forall x\in\mathcal M_*,~\underset{\omega\in\Omega}{\operatorname{ess sup}}|\langle f(\omega),x\rangle|=0\biggr\}$$

by quotienting in the linear surjection

$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathscr L_{*}^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal M)&\longrightarrow&\mathscr L^1(\Omega,\mathcal M_*)^*\\ f&\longmapsto&g\mapsto\int_\Omega\langle f(\omega),g(\omega)\rangle\,d\omega\end{array}$$

and through this identification, the operator norm of any coset $\tilde f\in\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M$ is given by

$$\|\tilde f\|_{\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M}=\inf_{f\in\tilde f}\underset{\omega\in\Omega}{\operatorname{ess sup}}\|f(\omega)\|_{\mathcal M}.$$

---

Now, in order to rigorously justify certain calculations in $\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M$, I want to be able to choose representatives of elements of $\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M$ in a nice way. I have been mostly satisfied with the "linear lifting of $\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M$ associated with a lifting" given by [A. & C. Ionescu-Tulcea, *Topics in the Theory of Liftings*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-88507-5), prop. 1 p. 77, but there are still situations for which I would like the lifting to be "multiplicative".

**So my question is** : does there necessarily exist a mapping $\rho:\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M\to\mathscr L_{*}^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal M)$ such that

- $\rho(\tilde f)\in\tilde f$,
- $\rho(\tilde f+\lambda\tilde g)(\omega)=\rho(\tilde f)(\omega)+\lambda\rho(\tilde g)(\omega)$,
- $\rho(\tilde f\tilde g)(\omega)=\rho(\tilde f)(\omega)\rho(\tilde g)(\omega)$,
- $\rho(1_{\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M})(\omega)=1_{\mathcal M}$,
- $\rho(\tilde f^*)(\omega)=(\rho(\tilde f)(\omega))^*$

for every $\tilde f,\tilde g\in\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M$, $\lambda\in\mathbf C$ and $\omega\in\Omega$ ?

**Remark** : the techniques used in A. & C. Ionescu-Tulcea's book to prove the existence of a multiplicative lifting for scalar functions cannot be easily adapted because in most cases, not every element of $\mathrm L^\infty(\Omega)\overline\otimes\mathcal M$ has a representative that is actually measurable and it is very unlikely that $\mathscr L_{*}^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal M)$ is an algebra under the naïve multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer: This is extremely unlikely to be true. At least when the lifting comes from a multiplicative lifting of scalar functions, it cannot be expected to be multiplicative everywhere. (I haven't read the exact details of the proposition you cited, but I presume it works similar to the following: Fix a multiplicative lifting $\rho$ of scalar functions. For any $\tilde{x} \in L^\infty(\Omega) \overline{\otimes} \mathcal{M}$, we lift it to $x$ defined by $x(\omega)(\phi) = \rho(Id \otimes \phi(\tilde{x}))(\omega)$ for all $\phi \in \mathcal{M}_*$ and $\omega \in \Omega$. Please correct me if this is not how the proposition works.)

I've been working on something related to this for a while now, and some of the proofs can be somewhat complicated so I'm unable to write a fully self-contained answer. Most but not all of the things here are contained in a note I posted on arXiv (https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.02086). Some things not contained in there can be proved by using the general ideas and the framework contained in that note.

Firstly, when $\mathcal{M}$ is separable, $\mathcal{L}^\infty_*(\Omega, \mathcal{M})$ is actually a $C^*$-algebra under pointwise multiplication and the quotient map $\mathcal{L}^\infty_*(\Omega, \mathcal{M}) \rightarrow L^\infty(\Omega) \overline{\otimes} \mathcal{M}$ is a $*$-homomorphism. And, for any lifting of scalar functions, the associated lifting $\rho: L^\infty(\Omega) \overline{\otimes} \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^\infty_*(\Omega, \mathcal{M})$ satisfies a weaker version of condition 3: for any $\tilde{f}, \tilde{g} \in L^\infty(\Omega) \overline{\otimes} \mathcal{M}$, $\rho(\tilde{f}\tilde{g})(\omega) = \rho(\tilde{f})(\omega)\rho(\tilde{g})(\omega)$ a.e. (See Chapter IV in the note, together with a discussion of liftings starting from Lemma V.12.) The problem is this co-null set on which condition 3 holds depends on $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$. In a simple case, consider $\Omega = ([0, 1], \lambda)$. For a lifting of scalar functions, the lifting followed by evaluation at any $t \in [0, 1]$ is a character on $L^\infty([0, 1])$. One can prove that any character on $L^\infty([0, 1])$ extends the concept of "limits at $t$" for some $t \in [0, 1]$ in a suitable way. For the map to be a lifting, the map followed by evaluation at $t \in [0, 1]$ must extend "limits at $t$" for a.e.-$t$, so for simplicity I'll just assume this holds for all $t$. (See Theorem III.4 and Theorem III.5 in the note.) Let $\mathcal{M} = R$, the hyperfinite $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor, $(v_n) \subseteq R$ a sequence of unitaries converging weakly to 0. For any $t \in [0, 1]$, one may then define a measurable function $\tilde{u_t}: [0, 1] \rightarrow R$, by dividing $[0, t)$ into infinitely many subintervals converging to $t$ and then filling in $v_n$. Similarly, divide $(t, 1]$ into infinitely many subintervals converging to $t$ and also fill in $v_n$. The point is now $\tilde{u_t}$ takes values in the unitary group a.e. but its limit at $t$ is 0. (This is similar to the discussion after Theorem V.18 in the note.) $\tilde{u_t}$ defines an element of the tensor product, which we shall also denote by $\tilde{u_t}$. Then, in the lifting, $u_t(t) = 0$. Similarly, $u_t^*(t) = 0$. But $\tilde{u_t}$ is a unitary, so the lifting of $\tilde{u_t}\tilde{u_t}^*$ is 1, whence the lifting map is not multiplicative at $t$. (If $\mathcal{M}$ needs not be separable, this can be even worse: You can take the direct sum of continuum many copies of $R$. Then by taking the direct sum of all $u_t$ above, you can show that the lifting map cannot even satisfies the weaker version of condition 3 mentioned before.)